# Leer cada fila de un archivo excel con asp net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Buenas tardes compañeros, necesito su apoyo por favor, ya que estoy empezando en asp.net framework. Lo que busco es poder leer cada fila de un Excel y esta poder almacenarla en una BDs de detallado. Estoy desarrollándolo en capas (MVC) y el código es el siguiente:

```
//Mi cadena de conexión para conectarme al archivo Excel:
    public class NCarga_Archivo
{

    OleDbConnection conexion;

    private OleDbConnection conectarExcel(string ruta)
    {
        conexion = new OleDbConnection();
        conexion.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = "+ ruta + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Macro; HDR = YES'";
       
        conexion.Open();
        return conexion;
    }

    public DataTable leerExcel(string ruta)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string query = "select * from [Hoja1$]";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conectarExcel(ruta));
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Desde mi formulario en la vista envio algunos parametros y tambien el archivo Excel, el mismo que ya esta guardado en un directorio asignado con el nombre "rutaGuardarArchivoExcel" donde el contenido del Excel es: TelefonoMovil, Dato1, Dato2. Estas 3 columnas son como su cabecera. Y en las filas siguientes esos datos de tipo: int, varchar(300), varchar(300).

```
                    //Ahora leeremos el archivo Excel
                DataTable data = obj_cls_cargaArchivo.leerExcel(rutaGuardarArchivoExcel);

                //validamos que el archivo excel tengo registros.
                if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int cantidad_registros = data.Rows.Count;
```

//Inserto los parametros recibidos por el formulario en una tabla consolidado

```
                    oArchivoCargado.insertControlConsolidadoEnvioSms(parCodCampania, parCodDetCampania, parCodPlantilla, nombreArchivoGuardar, cantidad_registros);

                    //Hacemos una comparación entre el archivo plantilla que esta en duro vs el archivo excel que se esta cargando
                    var lstColumnasArchivoPlantillaSms = new List<string>();
                    var lstColumnasArchivoSms = new List<string>();

                    foreach (DataColumn item in data.Columns)
                    {
                        lstColumnasArchivoSms.Add(item.ColumnName);
                    }

                    foreach (DataColumn items in dataPlantilla.Columns)
                    {
                        lstColumnasArchivoPlantillaSms.Add(items.ColumnName);
                    }
```

}

Compañeros, por lo que obtengo es solo los datos de la cabecera del excel, pero no su contenido. Este contenido es el que enviare a la bds sql server como detallado del consolidado, ante todo gracias por su ayuda.